# Use appendChild correctly to avoid XSS

Tags: javascript, xss, owasp

After doing an XXS site check, one error that pops up in the console is the inline use of the scripts needed for Google Analytics Tag Manager.
I have now created an external analytics.js file, which I load in the header and created an IIFE to load the script, then checked that it works in GA (it does):

```
var load_google_tag_manager = function(){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    script.async = true;
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXX-1";
    head.appendChild(script);
}();

window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXX-1', {
    "anonymize_ip": true,
    "allow_display_features": false,
    "link_attribution": false
});
```

I then checked the console again for error warnings and got one, this was the use of the function `appendChild`.
After reading some [OWASP documentation](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#guideline-3-use-documentcreateelement-elementsetattributevalue-elementappendchild-and-similar-to-build-dynamic-interfaces), I understand that using this can be potentially dangerous, and some good examples of how to make it safer are given, such as: how to use the `setAttribute` method. e.g.:

```
SAFE and FUNCTIONALLY CORRECT example

 var x = document.createElement("input");
 x.setAttribute("name", "company_name");
 x.setAttribute("value", '<%=Encoder.encodeForJS(companyName)%>');
 var form1 = document.forms[0];
 form1.appendChild(x);
```

But it does not say how to do this when you are e.g not using this method.
How would I e.g. set the `src` value safely?
Ultimately, I want to make my IIFE safe from XXS.

Comment: it may not even dangerous, but first please show you code.

Comment: well, I was thinking of encoding the url by doing the following:
 
```var url = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXX1";
script.src = "<%=Encoder.encodeForJS(Encoder.encodeForHTML(url))%>";```

Comment: @ Dan Well, there is zero risk of xss in that example (since the `url` is not dynamic)

Answer (score 1):

The encoding is needed in the example because of the mixing of server-side templating with client-side code. The quotes need to be escaped to prevent the string literal from being closed, and more code added after it.

So if `companyName` were `'); alert(1);//`, then:

```
x.setAttribute("value", '<%=companyName%>');
```

would become:

```
x.setAttribute("value", ''); alert(1);//');
```

Your URL looks like a fixed constant, so there is no possibility of something like this, so your code should be fine as it is.

Comment: This is great. I will pass this on to the tool that checks for [XXS](https://webbkoll.dataskydd.net/)